# About to take a longish vacation

Tags: united-states, vacation

**Some context**:  I have been with my company for over three years.  Good culture, great people in general.  I rolled over 5 days worth of vacation so I could take this trip.

I am about to go on my longest vacation ever in July (15 days), and I was curious if there were any known repercussions taking a *really* long vacation?

I have heard such things as "*if you are gone too long they will forget you were there*" or "*if the company can get along without you that long do they even need you.*"

Note: I admit a minor bit of paranoia could be in play here, and no I am **not gloating** about going on vacation.

Comment: Assuming you have appropriate backup when you are gone, they will hardly notice your absence. Just be sure to unplug 100% from your work.

Comment: Interesting cultural difference in place here. If you took 15 days of vacation where I live people would ask why you cut it so short, traditionally it's 4 weeks at a time during summer.

Comment: It's all in your head. They haven't hired a replacement just go. Have lots of fun.

Comment: Even in the USA some industry's "finance" for example you *must* take at least a 2 week break ,

Comment: After taking alllllllll that whopping barely 2 weeks off, you might be horrified to discover that you have no work-life balance at all, and that your job is stealing your life & offers really crappy benefits ... Or, you might come back refreshed and ready to tackle work tasks. Either way, unplug entirely & have a good trip. Also, set your "Out of Office" reply (this is a feature of most email software & similar tools used by people who sometimes leave their desk ... ask around for help).

Comment: In addition to what @mc01 said, find out who people should contact in your place while you are gone and add their contact details to your out-of-office message. Do not include any way of contacting you personally, and refer any sleazy contact attempts to that person.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

None at all.  As long as your manager and co workers know you're going of course.  Put it this way, your leave wouldn't have been approved if there was a chance that you being away for so long would cause significant problems.

Here in the UK, it's normal for people to take two weeks off in one go, companies seem to cope ok with the concept.

You might get back to find someone else has been using your desk for a while, but that's about it.

Go enjoy your vacation.  Forget about work, they won't forget about you.

Remember to bring back biscotti.

Comment: biscotti.....Do they have that in Italy?

Comment: Is that the Italy in Texas, or the Italy in Italy?  If it's the Italy in Italy, they'll have the best biscotti on Earth.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations.  You've earned the time off.  You have been gainfully employed by your company for three years.  If management does not have a problem then you shouldn't have one either.

Sometimes we (well at least me) like to think we're essential to the business.  I've learned through many years in the working world that I'm not - they will go on just fine without me.  A vacation allows you to come back refreshed and continue to do the fine job you have been (and will continue) doing.

Enjoy the trip.

Answer (score 2):

I have several coworkers who save vacation to take one long trip each year, it usually isn't a problem as long as:

1. They make sure all ongoing projects and day to day work can either be put on hold until they get back, or have someone covering for them.
2. It isn't during critical times where they are going to be needed (usually this is handled when they are requesting the time off)
3. They are still available if there are any major emergencies that need to be handled or minor questions that need answered (usually not a problem, may occasionally require 15-30mins every couple of days). But this third point depends on their job responsibilities.

If all of your work is taken care of you will have a blast! When you return your job will still be waiting and whoever is covering for you will be glad to have you back! Remember to do the same to help others who are taking vacations as well, and I doubt you will hear a single complaint.

Comment: Ugh. You expect the vacationer to get others to cover? This is what a manager does. And you expect emails or whatnot to be routinely answered throughout the vacation? That's not what a vacation is.

Comment: It depends on the job. Sometimes it isn't required, other times if you are the project lead on something, there may be a question that needs answered. Especially if you will be gone for three weeks. If it is only a week we usually wait for them to get back. Notice I said 15-30mins every couple of days. Over the course of a three week vacation that will probably be less than 2hrs total, at your own convenience. Three weeks can be a long time to be away from work. Managers can help get somebody to cover, but you will probably need to show them what to cover.

Comment: @KateGregory Although I agree with you, it does depend on the size (and culture) of the company. I've worked for small startups where you don't even _have_ a manager to coordinate things, and answering emails on vacation is expected. It's awful, and I don't miss that one bit.